# Outputting to multiple terminals

Tags: c, terminal, popen

I'm parsing a large log file.  I would like to pull out particular messages based on a severity classification (critical, warning, etc).  As I am parsing the log I would like to send messages, based on their severity, to a given, spawned, severity-specific, terminal.  The terminals should not close when the main program finishes reading the log file.  Environment is solaris 10/gcc 3.4.6.  I found the following example that captures what I was thinking of, but doesn't quite work (xterm spawns, but no output is sent to it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *output;
    int   i;

    output = popen ("xterm", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       fprintf (output, "%d\n", i);

    pclose (output);
}
```

I'm not married to xterm, I simply used it as handy and I do like the ability to title, color and size them.  I sort of get that writing to the handle generated by popen is not the same as writing to the terminal's output (just sort of...).  This *seems* like an easy thing to do.

Comment: gcc 3.4.6? Seriously? The current version is 5.1. Is there a good reason for using such an outdated version?

Comment: @stefan Sometimes, I have to code on gcc 2.95. "Environmental hazards" I suppose :)

Comment: Good reason? No.  I have no control over my environment in this regard.

Comment: Each xterm you open should show up as a new `/dev/pts/n` device.  You could simply write your output to stdout and stderr then redirect your programs output as `xterm; xterm; myprogram >/dev/pts/1 2>/dev/pts/2`.  Never tested, but should work.  You are limited to two terminals though.

Answer (score 0):

in general, what can be done is:

```
1) adjust your application so it can accept a parameter that indicates what level of severity to output to stdout.
2) open three terminals from the keyboard
3) run your application in each terminal, giving each execution the appropriate command line parameter
```

if your going to open the terminals from your application, for 'xterm' and others, the --hold parameter will stop the terminal from closing when you application exits

Comment: He's using Solaris 10 - cannot assume he has `-hold` in that particular xterm.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the pipe sounds reasonable, but there are a few problems:

- you cannot, of course, simply write to a newly-spawned terminal via a pipe.  xterm will ignore that; it is the application running within xterm which reads/writes from the pseudo-terminal.
- there is no way to scroll back in the messages sent to a given terminal
- the suggested writes to the pty device cannot be captured by a program running in the terminal

Rather than sending to a terminal, you might consider getting `xless` (a simple X application which might already be part of a package, but is simple enough to build), and structuring your output function to do this:

- for each message category, open a pipe to `xless` *once*
- write the message
- do not close the pipe

That would give you windows which do not close.  Here is a sample screenshot:
[image]

The source can be found on [ftp.x.org](ftp://ftp.x.org/contrib/applications/xless-1.7.tar.gz), as noted in the [Debian package description](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+source/xless/+copyright).

Comment: I like this answer but I wonder what you mean by "there is no way to scroll back in the messages sent to a given terminal". I assume you know about Shift+PgUp. (Actually I'm sure you do because I recognize your name)

Comment: I had in mind the fact that nothing running inside the terminal has any way to access this ...and after going past the `savedLines` limit, it's lost.  A pager is expected to do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the *great* responses, I do appreciate them!

OK, sounds like a slight re-design is called for =)  I did a quick prototype and it looks like it will work.  Will write the output to separate severity files, then when complete, pop up an xterm for each file, something like

```
sprintf (Crit, "xterm <yadda yadda> -e sh -c 'cat <crit-log>; <yadda yadda>');
popen (Crit, "r");
```

Writing to intermediate log files is actually a bonus should they need to be reviewed at a later time without having to go through the large-log-parsing program again.

Thanks again everyone!